# Use of MSMQ to control SQL write operations

Tags: msmq

Can I use MSMQ to reduce the number of synchronous write operations to a database and instead have the records written to the database every X number of minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't **reduce** the number of write operations by queuing them, but you can use a message queue to cluster the writes together.

That might be a *bit* more efficient (by dint of sharing a single connection), and could also let you schedule the writes at a convenient time if you wanted to ('every X minutes' wouldn't do that, but you could perform the writes during low usage times).

The increased complexity of that arrangement will normally outweigh the benefits - what do you really want to achieve?

Comment: we have an adverts impression tracking component that is killing our server so my thought is that if we use MSMQ then we can perform the write operations asynchronously at regular intervals. This is an Asp.net application which could potentially have a large number of users and potentially a large number of impressions needing to be recorded?

Comment: It's unlikely that performing those writes at intervals will take any significant pressure off your system. Do you know exactly where the problem is? (CPU usage, IO, lock contention, memory pressure, etc.?)

Comment: There's a lot of activity on the processor sure, but it seems the memory is more under pressure. I'm surprised that using something like MSMQ won't do the job. Just thinking about the basics here in terms of concurrent users and multiple concurrent actions between Asp.net and the DB. So are you thinking we should just up the hardware?